# Python 3.5, tkinter need a button to create a new class

Tags: python, class, button, lambda, tkinter

I've been making this python program (initially as a part of my school assignment, now just for my own use). The program actually worked just the way I wanted it to work, but I had made a ton of `x1 = Button(...)` etc lines, and I wanted to clean it up a little bit. Unfortunately my code is not actually written in English (which is kinda stupid, imo), so I don't think I will post the whole code here but just the part that I'm having problems with.

I thought I would make the buttons in a for-loop, and the buttons actually appear just the way I wanted them but pressing them actually does nothing. I want the buttons to start a new class (which will start a completely new window) and give the class one argument which would be an item from a list with the index i, and destroy the old window but no matter how I do it, the buttons will not do a single thing except for just be there.

```
for i in range(0, L):
        Button(self.__window, text=((str(i+1)+". "+lists[i])),
               padx=100, command=(self.__window.destroy, lambda j=i:
            Class2(lists[j]))).grid(row=(i+1), column=0, sticky=W + E)
```

Now, first I tried it without the lambda function just by making it

```
command=(self.__window.destroy, Class2(lists[i]))
```

but that didn't even create the buttons. Then I kept googling and found out about the lambdas, but I really don't have almost any information about the lambda-functions... Not sure if my lambda is even correct form!

Like I said, doing all these buttons manually without the lambda "worked" for it but I'm sure there must be an easier way to do what I want! Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: It would probably be easier to [move that stuff out of the `lambda` and into a named function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276033/using-lambda-and-tuples-to-send-to-multiple-functions-python-tkinter).

Comment: And it looks like that `destroy()` should be inside the `lambda` (also judging by the above-linked question).

Comment: Ahh, it was that simple! I feel a bit silly having not figured out that myself... Anyways, big thanks! I just made them into a named function and it instantly fixed my problem! :)